# Modernizr Check for CSS3 and cssanimations wont work

Tags: html, css, modernizr

I am having trouble redirecting my website if it detects that CSS3 is not supported. I use CSS3 animations so I decided to test for them but I can't get it to redirect let alone do an alert() message in my . Please help me out. Thank you!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>95.3 FM - KXLE Stream</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.custom.86596.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
<script> //THIS IS WHAT WILL NOT WORK********************************************
    if (!Modernizr.cssanimations) {
        window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
    }
</script>

</head>
```

Comment: definitely /should/ be working. Are you getting any errors in your console? Can you post a jsfiddle showing the same behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I was not pointing to the proper location of the modernizer js file in my head.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
   if (Modernizr.cssanimations) {
    window.location.replace("http://google.com");
    }
```